# How to specify path annotation in rest api java to accept any path?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am using jersey rest service in java to accept request.

Here is my snippet

```
    @Path("main")
    public class xxxx{
      @GET
      @Path("test/{path}")
      public void test(@Context HttpServletRequest req ) {
         System.out.println(req.getRequestURI());
      }
    }
```

I am invoking this using REST Api as test/abcd , it is working. I want @path to accept test/abcd or test/abcd/ab and so. I tried with "test/{path}/*" nothing works.

Please someone help me as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regex in the `@Path` for example :

```
@Path("{parameter: .*}")
Response getData(@PathParam("parameter") List<String> parameter){
     //do processing
}
```

For more details you can see the examples given [here](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-path-uri-matching-example/).